# DataGridViewColumn index gets changed after data clearing

Tags: c#, indexing, datagridview, display

After filling `DataSet`, I insert two `DataGridViewComboBoxColumns` into some particular index:

```
dgvPayments.Columns.Insert(1, cmbPayMethod);
dgvPayments.Columns.Insert(3, cmbPayType);
dgvPayments.Columns.Insert(5, cmbMonth);
```

I have a cell click event in this `DataGridView` where I check against the index:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)
{
 ...
}
```

The first time I load the data the column index hits the correct column, but after clearing data the column index does not. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your setup is thus:

1. In the form constructor, bind the `DataGridView.DataSource` to a collection.
2. In `Form.Load`, insert columns as you've shown in the OP.
3. "Clearing data" includes re-binding the `DataSource`.

   ```c#
   this.dataGridView.DataSource = emptyDataSource;
   ```

Then re-binding the `DataSource` essentially removes the sourced columns and readds them. This readjusts the manually inserted columns' indices to be the first ones - however it leaves the `DisplayIndex` untouched.

For example:

```c#
// DataSource added.
╔══════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║              ║ "Source 1" ║ "Source 2" ║ "Source 3" ║
╠══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ Index        ║     0      ║      1     ║      2     ║
║ DisplayIndex ║     0      ║      1     ║      2     ║
╚══════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝

// Column inserted at index 1.
╔══════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║              ║ "Source 1" ║ "Insert 1" ║ "Source 2" ║ "Source 3" ║
╠══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ Index        ║     0      ║      1     ║      2     ║      3     ║
║ DisplayIndex ║     0      ║      1     ║      2     ║      3     ║
╚══════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝

// DataSource rebound.
╔══════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║              ║ "Source 1" ║ "Insert 1" ║ "Source 2" ║ "Source 3" ║
╠══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ Index        ║     1      ║      0     ║      2     ║      3     ║
║ DisplayIndex ║     0      ║      1     ║      2     ║      3     ║
╚══════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

**Solution:**

Where you previously check for the index:

```c#
if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) // ==6 in your OP.
```

You could instead:

- Check that column's `DisplayIndex`:

  ```c#
  if (this.dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DisplayIndex == 1)
  ```
- Or, more preferably, check that column's `Name`:

  ```c#
  if (this.dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Insert 1")
  ```

Checking the `Name` is more reliable as it is less likely to change than the `DisplayIndex` and is more maintainable for future developers.